# Get monotonic time, same as CLOCK_MONOTONIC

Tags: go, time, clock

How can I get the monotonic time from boot in nanoseconds in Go? I need the same value that the following C code would return:

```
static unsigned long get_nsecs(void)
{
    struct timespec ts;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts);
    return ts.tv_sec * 1000000000UL + ts.tv_nsec;
}
```

The functions in the `time` package seem to return the current time and/or date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Go with [cgo](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/cgo).

Use `unsigned long long` to guarantee a 64-bit integer value for nanoseconds. For example, on Windows, `unsigned long` is a 32-bit integer value.

`monotonic.go`:

```
package main

import "fmt"

/*
#include <time.h>
static unsigned long long get_nsecs(void)
{
    struct timespec ts;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts);
    return (unsigned long long)ts.tv_sec * 1000000000UL + ts.tv_nsec;
}
*/
import "C"

func main() {
    monotonic := uint64(C.get_nsecs())
    fmt.Println(monotonic)
}
```

---

```
$ go run monotonic.go
10675342462493
$
```

Comment: This doesn't compile on macOS.

Comment: Works for me: MBP 2012, 10.14.6 Mojave, with xcode command line utils installed.  Your unspecified setup must be different.  And @rocka2q - Thanks for the simple cgo example - my first try at it! :-)

Comment: I have Big Sur with xcode command line utils on a 2019 MacBook Pro.

Comment: You probably deleted those comments before `import "C"`. Those also need to be included.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the syscall package.

```golang
import (
    "syscall"
    "unsafe"
)

func getNSecs() int64 {
    var ts syscall.Timespec
    syscall.Syscall(syscall.SYS_CLOCK_GETTIME, 4, uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&ts)), 0)
    return ts.Sec*1e9 + ts.Nsec
}
```