# How to get monotonic part of time.Time in Go

Tags: go, timestamp, clock

am currently working with timestamps and I would like to store in a variable the monotonic clock reading section.

Let's say that I have this: `2022-03-31 10:20:26.370463 +0200 CEST m=+0.007725255` then I would like to get `m=+0.007725255` in a different var, or at least the `+0.007725255` section. What is the idiomatic way in Go to get it?

Comment: https://pkg.go.dev/time#hdr-Monotonic_Clocks

Comment: this sounds like an XY problem, why do you want to have the monotonic reading in a separate variable?

Comment: related: [Get monotonic time, same as CLOCK_MONOTONIC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71401903/10197418)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Go [`time.Time`](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Time) stores 2 timestamps:

- Wall clock
- Monotonic duration since process start (optional, via [`time.Now`](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Now))

`m=+0.007725255` represents the monotonic duration since the start of the process (when present in a `time.Time`).

Go calculates this offset by recording `time.startNano` timestamp during initialisation (not public). `time.Now` uses `startNano` to calculate the monotonic duration stored in `time.Time`. There is no simple public API to directly retrieve this value since it should never be needed.

In practice, you should simply subtract 2 timestamps generated via `time.Now` in your current process and the result will be the monotonic duration. If you need to know the duration since process startup you should record a startup timestamp during initalisation.

Example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    t0 := time.Now()
    fmt.Println("...example event...")
    time.Sleep(time.Millisecond)
    t1 := time.Now()
    fmt.Println("Event start:", t0)
    fmt.Println("Event completed:", t1)

    fmt.Println("=== Not recommended ===")
    offsetT0, _ := monoOffset(t0)
    fmt.Println("Parsed start offset:", offsetT0)
    startNano, _ := calculateStartNano()
    fmt.Println("Calculate start offset via startNano: ", t0.Sub(startNano))

    fmt.Println("=== Recommended ===")
    fmt.Println("Example event duration:", t1.Sub(t0))
    fmt.Println("Time since startup", time.Since(t0))
}

// You should never need anything below here (code smell).

func monoOffset(t time.Time) (time.Duration, error) {
    // Recommend strings.Cut on Go1.18+.
    parts := strings.Split(t.String(), " m=")
    if len(parts) != 2 {
        return 0, errors.New("missing monotonic offset")
    }

    seconds, err := strconv.ParseFloat(parts[1], 64)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }

    nanos := math.Round(seconds * 1e9)
    return time.Duration(nanos), nil
}

func calculateStartNano() (time.Time, error) {
    now := time.Now()
    offset, err := monoOffset(now)
    if err != nil {
        return time.Time{}, err
    }
    return now.Add(-offset), nil
}
```

Outputs:

```
...example event...
Event start: 2022-04-16 16:54:25.088159496 +1000 AEST m=+0.000079273
Event completed: 2022-04-16 16:54:25.089438935 +1000 AEST m=+0.001358685
=== Not recommended ===
Parsed start offset : 79.273µs
Calculate start offset via startNano:  79.273µs
=== Recommended ===
Example event duration: 1.279412ms
Time since startup 2.016789ms
```

Answer (score 0):

The monotonic clock is just used for differences between times.  The absolute value of the monotonic clock is undefined and you should not try to get it.  I think what you really want for your timestamp is the duration from a base time.

```
func init() {
    baseTime = time.Now()
}

// NowTimestamp returns really just the duration from the base time
func NowTimestamp() time.Duration {
    return time.Now().Sub(baseTime)
}
```